# How to get one component of a tikz/PGF coordinate?

Tags: latex, tikz, pgf

I'm trying to draw a horizontal line across my diagram. The Y coordinate of the line should be halfway between points a and b (a is below b). The left and right endpoints of the line are on the bounding box of the tikzpicture. Here's how I'm doing this now, using the intersection operator:

```
\coordinate (h0) at ($(a.north)!0.5!(b.south)$);
\draw (h0 -| current bounding box.west) -- (h0 -| current bounding box.east);
```

This strikes me as rather roundabout. What I'd rather do is get the Y coordinate of (h0) and the X coordinates of the east and west sides of the bounding box, and compose the coordinates myself. I'd like to do this, but it isn't supported syntax:

```
\coordinate (h0) at ($(a.north)!0.5!(b.south)$);
\draw (current bounding box.west.x,h0.y) -- (current bounding box.east.x,h0.y);
```

Is there a way to reference individual components of coordinates that I'm missing?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can get at the components inside a `let` operation. Look it up in the PGF manual for the works, but from memory:

```
\draw
  let
    \p1=($(a.north)!0.5!(b.south)$),
    \p2=(current bounding box.west),
    \p3=(current bounding box.east)
  in
    (\x2,\y1) -- (\x3, \y1);
```

That'll probably need debugging... EDIT: and now has been thanks to the questioner.

Comment: Thanks! Debugging: The comma ending the `\p3` line needs to be deleted, `a.north` needs a closing ')' and `b.south` needs an opening '('. Once that's done, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 11):

Alternatively, use

```
\pgfextractx{<dimension>}{<point>}
\pgfextracty{<dimension>}{<point>}
```

These are raw PGF commands, so it may be less convenient to use them.

Comment: But `<point>` really needs to be a lowlevel pgfpoint. To make it work with points defined using `\coordinate at ...`, you have to say `\pgfpointanchor{coordinate}{center}`, since `\coordinate (coordinate) at (1,2);` defines a node of shape coordinate (having one ancher called center) and \pgfpointanchor returns the pgf lowlevel point for this anchor.

Comment: @leemes Any idea how to make `\pgfpointanchor` work for pgfpoints (i.e. if the coordinate is in fact a pgfpoint, then just return that point)? Or maybe to make the distinction between pgfpoints and coordinate? I'm asking because in path `\tikztotarget` can be both a point or a coordinate depending on whether the start is `A` or `A.east`.

Answer (score 5):

Another option I just found from [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/multiplexer/) shows that you can get relative positioning from a node by doing this:

```
\node at (2, 1) (a) {};
\draw (a) -- ++(right:2);
```

This will draw a line from node a to the point 2 units to the right of point a.  Like in the example I linked, this is useful when you don't know the exact coordinates of a node, and need to draw things relative to it.